# Problema VBA y Excel con fechas

Tags: excel, vba, date, formato

Tengo un fichero .dmp en donde vienen todas las fechas de un mes, por ejemplo:

```
01/12/2017
02/12/2017
03/12/2017
...
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa excel VBA para ponerlas en celdas, las transforma en:

```
12/01/2017
12/02/2017
...
```

Hasta el dia 13 que, al no haber mes 13, pues no lo cambia. Este es mi código y ya no se que hacer:

```html
Cells(1, 1).Select
    
        If Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
            Rows("4:4").Select
            selection.Copy
            Rows("1:1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
            Rows("1:1").Select
            selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Rows("4:4").Select
            selection.Copy
            Rows("1:1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Rows("3:3").Select
    selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    
    Tini = Range("C3") & " " & Range("D3")
    Tfin = Range("F3") & " " & Range("G3")
    Rows("3:4").Select
    selection.ClearContents
    Cells(3, 1).Value = Tini
    Cells(4, 1).Value = Tfin
    Range("A3:A4").Select
    selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yy hh:mm:ss"
```

Gracias

Comment: verifica en las celdas de escritura en que formato de fecha esta excel maneja varios formatos.

Comment: En excel esta en formato dd/mmm/yyyy, o sea el que yo quiero, el problema es que al pasar por el VBA los dias pasas a meses y viceversa aunque en el excel siga estando el formato como dd/mmm/yyyy. Quiero decir en el archivo .dmp yo lo tengo como dd/mmm/yyyy, despues al llegar a excel lo unico que sucede es que las cifras se mueven sin moverse el formato

Comment: Entonces lo único que se me ocurre es que esos valores los pases como string y la celdas le quites los formatos y lo dejes como texto

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Que hay dentro de `Tini` y `Tfin`? ¿Cómo las tienes definidas? Concatenas valores en ambos casos, incluyendo un espacio en blanco (por ejemplo, `Range("C3") & " " & Range("D3")`) y los pones en A3 y A4. Y luego quieres pasarlos a fechas? Necesitamos más datos y ejemplos o será difícil ayudarte

Comment: Dentro de Tini y Tfin hay un valor de tiempo inicial y uno final. O sea en si son valores de fechas ya, el problema es que luego se intercambian el mes y el dia. El Tfin no se intercambia ya que es el 31/12 pero el Tini si cambia de 01/12 al 12/01.

Comment: Al final encontré la solucion buscando en mas paginas y foros, solo habia que añadir `Local:=True` cuando se abria el fichero:
`Workbooks.Open Filename:="c:\Excel\MyFile.csv",Local:=True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final encontré la solucion buscando en mas paginas y foros, solo habia que añadir Local:=True cuando se abria el fichero:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="c:\Excel\MyFile.csv",Local:=True
```